# Using If-else instead of ternary operator in map function to set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-operator

The objective of the function is to toggle the reminder property of the task object when the task is being double clicked.

I am trying to create other similar functions to replace the tutorial code such as instead of using map, I would instead use a for loop. However, upon trying to use if-else condition within the map rather than ternary operators the state of the task ends up being undefined. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

***Tutorial Code (Working)***

```
setTasks(tasks.map((task) => 
  task.id === id ? { ... task, reminder : !task.reminder} : task
));
```

***For Loop Variation (Working)***

```
let tempTasks = [];
for(let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i ++){
  if(tasks[i].id == id){
    let newObj = {};
    newObj['id'] = tasks[i].id;
    newObj['text'] = tasks[i].text;
    newObj['day'] = tasks[i].day;
    if(tasks[i].reminder === true){
      newObj['reminder'] = false;
    }
    else{
      newObj['reminder'] = true;
    }
    tempTasks.push(newObj);
  }
  else{
    tempTasks.push(tasks[i]);
  }
}
setTasks(tempTasks);
```

***Map Variation Using If Else ( Not Working )***

```
setTasks(tasks.map((task) => {
  if(task.id === id){
    task.id = task.id;
    task.text = task.text;
    task.reminder = true;
  }
  else{
    task = task;
  }
} ));
```

Comment: Can you clarify what these lines are meant to do? `task.id = task.id;
    task.text = task.text;`. Don't they set the the variables to their current values?

Comment: Your arrow function doesn't return anything.

Comment: (Noting that "map variation" treats `reminder` differently than the others.)

Comment: @mykaf yes, i only want to update the reminder property. The rest are to remain the same

Comment: @YeoBryan I think the point was that it's not necessary to set them to themselves.

Comment: @DaveNewton why doesn't the tutorial code using map have to include return in the code but my variation of it requires a return?

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh i get what you mean by the code setting the id / text etc not being needed. Thank you!

Comment: @YeoBryan See [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description), particularly the part about braces. Your arrow function has braces, so it needs an explicit return.

Comment: @YeoBryan Noting again that last version acts differently than the first two.

Comment: @DaveNewton Kindly post your response as an answer so that i can mark it as correct. It has resolved my issue! Thank you!!

Comment: @YeoBryan There's already a correct answer (which duplicates the different behavior for `reminder`).

Comment: @DaveNewton But in my opinion it was better explained in the comments here, i can mark his answer as correct though if that is the standard procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to return the object.

```
setTasks(tasks.map((task) => {

  if(task.id === id){
    task.id = task.id;
    task.text = task.text;
    task.reminder = true;
  } 

 return task
}
```

Comment: omg... this solved the issue. Thank you!! but why dont the tutorial code need a return?

Comment: maybe a typo. also you don't need the else condition too

Comment: I dont think there is a typo in the tutorial code since it works though